# contact form using php in angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, forms, post

html :

View/contactform.html

```
<form method="post" role="form"  name="myemailform" action="sendingemail.php">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                    <div class="validation"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                    <div class="validation"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                    <div class="validation"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" cols="10" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    <div class="validation"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center"><input type="submit" class="btn applyBtn" name="submit"/></div>
              </form>
```

PHP:

view/sendingemail.php

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_from = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$emails = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$emails .= "Name: $name \r\n";

$emails .= "Message: $message \r\n";



mail('sunitha_anilkumar@yahoo.com',$subject,$emails);
echo 'Mail sent!';
header('Location: thank-you.html');
?>
```

app.js

```
.when('/contactus', {

                templateUrl: 'view/contactform.html',
                controllerAs:'vm'
            })
```

I wanted a contact form in my angular project and I given the form in view/contactform.html and sendingemail.php for submitting the form details. But when I submit the form, i am just seeing the sendingemail.php code , no form submission is done.Need assistance.

[image: form submission]

Comment: Do you have apache configured correctly?

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Comment: i am using apache server

Answer (score -1):

This means your webserver does not recognise your php file to be run as a php file. You might want to check your webserver's documentation to install and/or enable the PHP module.